# Retrieve images from users phone

Tags: java, android

I have created a functional image gallery that takes photos from a user's phone and displays it on a `recyclerview`. Everything works, however, it seems as though the method I have used to retrieve this data is limited to API level 29. The app is meant to work on devices API 21 and up. How can I adjust this code to accommodate this?

**RetrieveImgaes.java**

```
public class SelectImagesGallery {

  public static ArrayList < String > listOfImages(Context context) {

    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor;
    int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;
    ArrayList < String > listOfAllImages = new ArrayList < > ();
    String absolutePathOfImage;
    uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = {
      MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
      MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
    };

    String orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");

    column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);

    // Get folder name
    // column_index_folder_name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
      absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
      listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);
    }


    return listOfAllImages;
  }
```

Comment: Get rid of the `DATA` reference. Query for `ID` instead, and use `ContentUris.withAppendedId()` to generate a `Uri` for the image. Return a `List<Uri>`, and hand the `Uri` over to your preferred image-loading library (e.g., Glide, Picasso).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm having a bit of difficulty fully understanding your answer. Would you please adjust the code, so that I can better understand? Thank you :)